# How to connect VOIP to PSTN?

Tags: voip

How to connect VOIP to PSTN? I have read a lot about VOIP to VOIP. But how is it possible to connect VOIP to PSTN? I have tried to search after this information on Google without success.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on type of your PSTN lines. In short, for T1/E1 you can use big carrier-grade gateways, Cisco for example, and for 2-wire POTS lines you can use small phone adapters with FXS/FXO ports, such as Audiocodes or Linksys. They are SIP-based, so you will need to register them as SIP endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The interworking that you mention is generally performed on a SoftSwitch. These are any to any Signaling protocol conversion. So a very common scenario is what you referred to as VoIP to PSTN or vice versa. I am using SIP to ISUP as a example here.

Usually the PSTN side can be broken to Signaling Gateways and Media Gateways. While the Signaling GW converts the SIP Request / Response to equivalent Signaling message, the SDP is used to control the Media Gateway  based on MEGACO or MGCP. For a normal SIP Call these shall be the conversion for the signaling message. Similar rules apply for H323 to PSTN conversion.

### **INVITE + SDP -> IAM 180 / 183 -> ACM / CPG 200 -> ANM / CON BYE -> REL**

You can check RFC 3398 to check some of these SIP to PSTN conversion rules.

There was another mechanism ITU-Q.1912.5 where the entire ASN encoded ISUP Message body is carried as part of the MIME attachment of the SIP Message and then the message is extracted and sent to the SS7 network. This was part of IPX / GSX [Global Switching Exchange] where the messages across long hops shall be carried over VoIP and on its last mile be converted to equivalent ISUP Signaling.

Now if you are only interested in knowing how a SIP UA can be terminated on a Mobile phone you need to have a partnership with one of the VoIP carriers that provide ISUP Termination capabilities. But somewhere in there switching equipment they will be having mechanisms similar to what is explained above.

Answer (score 0):

There are ATA devices that have a VOIP as well as a POTS port and can connect calls between them. Linksys SPA3102 is one such device. These things are extremely configurable and you can have them automatically answer voip calls and provide a PSTN dial tone or automatically call preset phone numbers.